# Wexflow create my task using .NET Core project

Tags: .net-core, workflow

I've installed Wexflow, version dot NET Core. I want to create my own task. Project is in .NET Core.
I added Wexflow library using this command:

```
dotnet add package Wexflow
```

Library has been added to depenedencies, but there is same bug. It looks like below:
[image]
My WexflowSampleTask is in NET Core 2.2. But there is compatibility issue I think.
I code I can't add Wexflow namespace. When I type use Wexflow, I get error that namespace doesn't exist.

```
using System;
using Wexflow.Core;

namespace WexflowSampleTask
{
    public class MyTaskNetCore : Task
    {
    }
}
```

Type or namespace Wexflow couldn't be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [Wexflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Wexflow/) nuget package is rather poorly configured - it does not declare platforms that are supported. For comparison, take a look at [log4net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/) package - under Dependencies section you see all target frameworks that are supported (.NETFramework 2.0, 4.0, .NETStandard 1.3, etc). `Wexflow` does not do that so you can install it to absolutely any project.

If you unpack nuget package, then you can see that this nuget package supports only .NETFramework 4.6.1 or .NET Core 3 target platforms.

Your application [still can be compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797892/net-core-2-0-package-was-restored-using-netframework-4-6-1-instead-of-target) and executed though, compiler just warns you that it might be incompatible at runtime because it is restored for a different target:

```
warning NU1701: Package 'Wexflow 5.1.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Comment: so no wexflow compatibility with .net core 2.2?